# If else condition using database in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to  make an if else statement in my project but I don't know how to make an else statement that has a condition that if the barcode number that has been entered on the edit text is not from the database, it would display a certain message...how can i achieve this? Thanks in advance

Here is my line of codes too

```
public void scan (View v){

imageArray.clear();
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
EditText barcode= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
String barcodenum;
barcodenum=barcode.getText().toString();

if (barcodenum.equals("")){
    Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "You've entered an empty barcode number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if (barcodenum!=){ //This is the line im talking about
    Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "The barcode you've entered doesn't exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if (barcodenum!=null){
    Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Showing the item you've searched!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


barcode.setText("");
ImageView front=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
front.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
imageArray.add(db.getItems(Integer.valueOf(barcodenum)));
adapter1=new ItemImageAdapter(this,R.layout.soloitem,imageArray);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter1);

goback();

ImageButton btnGoBack=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
btnGoBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

MakeItemsInvisible();
}
```

Here is the DatabaseHandler for getItems

```
 Items getItems(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TBL_ITEMS, new String[] {ITEM_ID, ITEM_BARCODE ,ITEM_NAME,
            ITEM_PRICE ,ITEM_CATEGORY, ITEM_IMG, ITEM_CLICKED }, ITEM_BARCODE + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null );
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    Items items = new Items(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)),
            cursor.getString(2),Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(3))
            ,cursor.getString(4),cursor.getBlob(5),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)));

    // return item
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just query the database to see if the entered barcode number exists?

Comment: @katzoft I got confused with that....can you make a sample?

Comment: I don't have the code for your DatabaseHandler, but I would assume that something like db.getItems(Integer.valueOf(barcodenum)).count() == 0 would do the trick.

Comment: @katzoft I've added my DatabaseHandler for db.getItems can you please look at it? Thank you so much for helping i'm getting great ideas

Comment: @katzoft I tried using the else if(db.getItems(Integer.valueOf(barcodenum)).count() == 0) but it gives me some kind of error.

Comment: Count() was just an example to give you an idea. You have to replace it with a method that returns the number of items in in an Items object.

Comment: @katzoft i still cant make it work :(